# puppet modules using command instead of vagrant provisioning

Tags: vagrant, puppet, devops, provisioning

I have a project where they are using Vagrant provision to load puppet modules. the modules are available in a directory inside the project most of them are git projects.

I'm a beginner in using puppet, I'm asking if there is a way to install those modules without using vagrant provision. 
Can I install them one by one, I tried this but modules are coupled, I think there is a way to install them all at one time

help please !

Answer (score 0):

I generally work the following way: From Vagrantfile, I have a script which will install all my puppet modules directly in the VM - in the Vagrantfile, something likes:

```
config.vm.provision "shell", path: "script/install-puppet-modules.sh"
```

and my script file will be something like:

```
#!/bin/bash

mkdir -p /etc/puppet/modules;

if [ ! -d /etc/puppet/modules/example42-perl ]; then
  puppet module install example42-perl --version 2.0.20
fi

if [ ! -d /etc/puppet/modules/puppetlabs-apache ]; then
  puppet module install puppetlabs-apache --version 1.5.0
fi

if [ ! -d /etc/puppet/modules/puppetlabs-java ]; then
  puppet module install puppetlabs-java --version 1.4.1
fi
```

so I do not need to maintain the modules in my project directory, when it installs the modules, it will install with all dependencies and the specified version.

Comment: what about applying your own modules ?